# hidden navigation bar causing trouble with action sheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiactionsheet

[image]

The navigation bar in my uinavigationbarcontroller is hidden, but my actionsheet thinks its still there, hence giving me a the highlights at the top of the action page (seen above). How can I erase this/ trick my actionsheet into thinking its a normal uiimageview?

Navigation bar hidden like so in didLoad:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

and:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    }
}
```

actionsheet looks like this in didLoad:

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200,320,16)];
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done_clicked:)];

    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];

UIPickerView *locationPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
locationPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 216);
locationPicker.delegate  = self;
locationPicker.dataSource = self;
locationPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
locationPicker.tag = 1;
[actionSheet addSubview:locationPicker];
```

Then its animated in on textfield touch.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == locationTextField.self)
    {
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us help you: Post some code. I think it depends on where you are trying to show the action sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the view you chose to show the action sheet. try to show it in your app's main window.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried:         [actionSheet showInView:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]];
 but no joy.